# Public key encryption vs private key encryption

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, private-key

I have implemented **asymmetric encryption** in my project using "public key" to "encrypt" the message and "private key" to "decrypt" the message.

Do we ever use "private key" to "encrypt" the message and and "public key" to "decrypt". If yes, can someone give me a use case of that and is this kind of cryptography also called "asymmetric encryption"

Comment: Simple example for using your private key to encrypt something would be *signing* some document/text/hash thereof/...

Comment: See Crypto.SE: [How does asymmetric encryption work?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/292/how-does-asymmetric-encryption-work)

Comment: @ArtjomB. I tried to explain more extensively [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15997/is-rsa-encryption-the-same-as-signature-generation) - not with too much success in upvotes though. Maybe too complex an explanation.

Comment: @owlstead I originally searched for something like that, but haven't found it. Great self-post. It certainly is not too complex for Crypto.SE, but SO users might have problems with this.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I've restructured that answer, hopefully it's easier to read now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as the term *encryption* is considered to be *on the message itself*, the answer is **no** because such an encryption is totally useless. Since the public key is supposed to be public everyone could use it to decrypt. Encrypting with the private key thus fails to provide confidentiality.

Signing on the other side, as others have already mentioned is the only use case for this. It does not apply the encryption to the actual payload (the message). It encrypts a cryptographic hash over the message (that can be reproduced from the same message only), using a different *padding scheme*. In this way you can be sure the actual party that has the private key signed the message.

Answer (score 2):

Asymmetric means you cannot use the same key for decryption that you used for encryption.
Code signing is one scenario where you encrypt using the private key. Recipients of the code can then use their public key to verify if the code was unchanged.

Comment: Never confuse encryption with signing, not even for RSA. It's true that modular exponentiation is used for both, but that's where the comparison ends. Even the modular exponentiation is explicitly given a different name in the PKCS#1 specifications, and then there is the difference in padding and hashing...

Comment: Applied Cryptography-Bruce Schneier (1.1. Terminology): "Sometimes, messages will be encrypted with the private key and decrypted with the public key; this is used in digital signatures." With regard to RSA of course and in general sense. Agree with previous comment in real world where details matter. Some libraries do not allow to encrypt with private key - MS CryptoAPI for example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking is called asymmetric, rather RSA public/private key encryption. And yes you could use both keys to encrypt and decrypt but there are 2 separate issues.

Secrecy - encrypt with public key and only the private key could decrypt. The enclosed message is secure

Authentication - encrypt with private key and anyone with public key could decrypt. Secrecy is not offered however if the public key decrypts successfully, you're sure of who I am because if anyone tampers with the message then the public key won't decrypt it